# SharePoint 2013 - Cascading dropdown fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint 2013 form that has 2 dropdown fields. I'm looking for a way to populate the 2nd dropdown field depending on the selection in the 1st dropdown field.

For example, a form would have a State dropdown field followed by a City dropdown field. The City dropdown field is populated only with cities found in the state selected in the State dropdown field.

Any comments, references, tips, suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It did cascading dropdown in a webpart. I added the following code in my .ascx. Two dropdown values are populated from the list.

The code will do as follows. First dropdown takes values from state list and load in stateddl . On change city function will be called with filters the city from the selected state and load . City details is stored in city list. (I have altered the variable name,list name which i used for my work. So check once. But this code format is right)

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(statepopulate, "sp.js");

var _ctx = null;
    var _web = null;
    var _allstate = null;
    var _allstate1 = null;
    var _ctx1 = null;
    var _web1 = null;
    var state = null;
    var city = null;
 

function statepopulate() {
        //Get the list
        _ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        _web = _ctx.get_web();
        var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle("State");
        //Create the query and get the results
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
        _allcountry = list.getItems(query);
        _ctx.load(_allstate, 'Include(Title,ID)');
        _ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.statepopulatesuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.statepopulatefailed));

    }
    function statepopulatesuccess() {
        //Clear out current entries
        var ddlstate = this.document.getElementById("ddlstate");
        ddlstate.options.length = 0;
        //Iterate through new entries and populate DDL
        var listEnumerator = _allcountry.getEnumerator();
        ddlcountry.options[ddlcountry.options.length] = new Option("Select state", 0);
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            ddlstate.options[ddlcountry.options.length] = new Option(currentItem.get_item("Title"), currentItem.get_item("ID"));

        }
    }

    function statepopulatefailed() {

    }


    function city() {
        _ctx1 = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        _web1 = _ctx1.get_web();
        state = document.getElementById("ddlstate").value;
        var list1 = _web.get_lists().getByTitle("city");
        var query1 = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query1.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' /><Value Type=\'Counter\'>' + state + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>');
        _allcity1 = list1.getItems(query1);
        _ctx1.load(_allpractice1, 'Include(state,ID,Title)');
        _ctx1.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.citypopulatesuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.citypopulatefailed));

    }


    function citypopulatesuccess() {
        var ddlcity = this.document.getElementById("ddlcity");
        ddlcity.options.length = 0;
        var listEnumerator = _allcity1.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            if (state == currentItem.get_item("ID")) {
                for (var i = 0; i < currentItem.get_item("state").length; i++) {
                    ddlcity.options[ddlcity.options.length] = new Option(currentItem.get_item("Title")[i], currentItem.get_item("ID")[i]);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function citypopulatefailed() {
        alert("failes");
    }


</script>
```

```html
<td class="" align="left">
       
            State<sup class= "supspt">*</sup></td>
        <td class="style2" align="left">
        <div class="boxid1"><select id="ddlstate"  class="selectclass" onChange="city();"></select>
            
           </div></td>
    </tr>

 <tr>
        <td class="style3" align="left">
       
            City<sup class= "supspt">*</sup></td>
        <td class="style2" align="left">
        <div class="boxid1"><select id="ddlcity"  class="selectclass"><Option>Select City</option></select>
            
           </div></td>
    </tr>
```